# Can I buy a wireless access point that also acts as a DNS nameserver?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, dns

I was wondering if I buy a wireless access point/router that also acts as a DNS nameserver for DHCP clients. I can see the hostnames of my home devices in the DHCP clients table of the router I have, it doesn't seem like a great leap of the imagination to have a local nameserver on there, something like hostname.home that automatically publishes those entries to a local zone.

But - I can't find one that does that. Is there a reason why this shouldn't/can't be done? Or is my Google-Fu just weak?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say buy a Linksys WRT54GL and flash it to either Tomato, or DD-WRT.  You could turn off DHCP I suppose and only utilize the DNS portion.

Answer (score 0):

Most don't do that because BIND requires more memory than they have to offer, and few consumers would pay more for a device they know even less about how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Any custom Linux firmware, such as OpenWRT, with the [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) package, will automatically seed its DNS server with DHCP client names.  However, I am not aware of any wireless access point that has that feature out of the box.